What are my options (for the benefit of my son) to move stock out of a UTMA so it does not count against him with the FAFSA?
I have a UTMA for my son and it has nvidia stock amongst others. It has done well.
We are otherwise low income with no assets.
I know the Fafsa application will have this count against him. I want to move the stock vs sell it to set him up for the best financial aid package we can get. What are my options to move the stock. My son's grandpa is willing to hold the stock. This is all for his benefit which are the rules of the UTMA.

How old is the son? Also, generally committing crimes for the child benefit is still committing crimes.

How is this a crime? Serious question. He is 17.

See the answer I posted. You're trying to falsify statements for FAFSA purposes. The child doesn't really want to gift the stock to grandpa, you're just trying to hide it.

Seems to me that the trust is doing it's job - providing an education to your son.

FAFSA fraud is generally covered by the 18 USC 1001:

(a) Except as otherwise provided in this section, whoever, in any matter within the jurisdiction of the executive, legislative, or judicial branch of the Government of the United States, knowingly and willfully—
(1) falsifies, conceals, or covers up by any trick, scheme, or device a material fact;
(2) makes any materially false, fictitious, or fraudulent statement or representation; or
(3) makes or uses any false writing or document knowing the same to contain any materially false, fictitious, or fraudulent statement or entry;
shall be fined under this title, imprisoned not more than 5 years or, if the offense involves international or domestic terrorism (as defined in section 2331), imprisoned not more than 8 years, or both. If the matter relates to an offense under chapter 109A, 109B, 110, or 117, or section 1591, then the term of imprisonment imposed under this section shall be not more than 8 years.

I highlighted the parts relevant to your plan and the punishment. The fine can be up to $20000, IIRC.
